# Rails sending cached page for guest users only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I am a newbie in caching so it might be obvious.

I want to achieve something like that:

1. User is not logged. He gets cached page.
2. User is logged in. He gets plain page, not cached one.

Something like that(pseudocode):

`caches_action :index, :if => !current_user`

Unfortunately this doesnt work, but I guess you go the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

`caches_action :index, :unless => :current_user`

Answer (score 3):

Since page caching actually saves a `.html` file that the web server picks up directly, by-passing Rails entirely, you can't use this method.

A better approach might be to cache the contents of the page conditionally. I usually implement a `cache_if` method that wraps around the view `cache` method and can take a condition:

```
def cache_if(condition, *options, &block)
  if (!condition)
    yield
  else
    cache(*options, &block)
  end
end
```

It would look like this when used:

```
<% cache_if(!current_user, '#content') %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: This isnt page caching. It is action caching. Anyway you provide an interesting approach to cache conditionally. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can see up a [Cache Sweeper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers) for user sessions. So basically you can set it up as when a UserSession is created, expire the cache page. The linked Rails docs on sweepers is excellent.